# Are fairy rings documented as a growth pattern in ferns?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

I planted an *Onoclea sensibilis*, a single plant, in my garden. After the first season, there was signs that a fairy ring was forming. A few years later it was mostly complete, but then was obscured in the following years by the growth of the next generation ferns on the ring.

I have not seen any documentation in my field guides that sensibilis or any other fern creates a fairy ring.

I would believe that the fairy rings would be rare in the field.

Where would I find documentation on fern fairy rings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this was the only result I could find about Onoclea sensibilis fern ring I wanted to add a reference to a wild fern ring I found of the species. This was found in the fall, 2022, in WV during a hike. I do not know the age of the patch of ferns.

This response, I hope, should act as an answer to the question for documentation of a sensibilis fern fairy ring.

As reference and showing ownership of copyright, I originally posted this image on instagram here: https://www.instagram.com/p/CiTl_VvjXq5/

[image: Onoclea sensibilis fern fairy ring]